# Infinite loop in Mac OS X "od -c" (and perhaps FreeBSD)

Tags: c, macos, infinite-loop, freebsd, bsd

Try this on Mac OS X (don't worry, it won't crash your computer, it just spins):

```
printf "\314" | od -c
```

It seems that character `0314` somehow tricks `od` in its default Unicode mode (!) to look for further input, but there is none.  I browsed the source a bit: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-175/hexdump/conv.c

It seems like the bug is where it does `goto retry;` but I'm not sure.  My question is: is this really where the bug is, and how would you fix it?

---

For bonus points, here's a command that outright crashes, due to another bug reported on the [Free BSD bugs mailing list](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-bugs/2006-July/019369.html) in 2006:

```
printf "\314\217" | od -c
```

This is still not fixed in Mac OS X, and apparently [not in FreeBSD either](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/freebsd/usr.bin/hexdump/conv.c), but at least it isn't an [infinite loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_Loop_(street))!  This one really makes me wonder, because it's not just these two characters which cause it--you can run `od -c` on a wide variety of large binary files and watch it crash.  Do people really not use `od` much since 2006?

Comment: [File a bug report with Apple?](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: I tend to use `xxd` these days - it is more flexible to my mind.

Comment: This looks to be fixed in yosemite - I'm not seeing either the SEGV or a spin of od when I use your examples.

Comment: enough to use `od -c /dev/random` and will crash everytime ;) the infinite loop isn't common, because here are small number of (correct) files what **ends** to few characters causing the loop.